# Liquibase Ordered Includes

Tags: liquibase

I would like to create a separate change log for each version of my application (for example 1.0_changelog.xml, 1.0.1_changelog.xml, 1.1_changelog.xml, etc.). I would like to be able to include these change logs in a single-direction chain where the head is the most recent change log which has an include tag for the next most recent change log etc. until the root version (no looping back to head). I would like this list of change logs to evaluate from root to head.

I've been studying the documentation and StackOverflow, and according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907483/liquibase-execution-order-of-changeset-files-when-using-includeall-with-classpat), it is not currently possible because of the way liquibase orders includes. If I am wrong, how would I go about implementing this? If I am not wrong, would any liquibase devs mind if I created an Improvement issue in the liquibase JIRA for this?

If there is not a way to do it now, I am probably going to end up implementing this myself as a gradle plugin that enforces the ordering by executing the liquibase command with each file individually. If I resort to this, I will provide links in an answer.

Comment: Did you come across the liquibase [best practices](http://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html)? It suggests to use a master changelog xml file which includes all other files (`1.0_changelog.xml, 1.0.1_changelog.xml, etc`. I think you could definitively file an improvement issue in Jira but I guess you would have to explain why the solution of chaining the changelog files is a better approach then using a master changelog.

Comment: I seem to think I read that at some point, but I must have forgotten about that. That will actually suit my needs. The main difference would be the slight increase in brevity for branching chains by doing it the way I suggested vs. a fairly major increase in visibility doing it the recommended way. I suppose my change would also need some sort of command to print the chain in order to maintain the same level of visibility, but it doesn't sound worth the effort. Thanks a lot! You saved me a ton of time. Put that in an answer, and I'll mark it.